# Is it insecure to include your login page in your single page application?

Tags: security, authentication, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

My understanding is that, if you include your login page in your SPA, then the user is receiving all of your code before they're even authenticated. And yet, it seems to be a very common practice. Isn't this incredibly insecure?? Why or why not?

Comment: Anything the client has, the client has.. if it's providing 'sensitive' information belong to *[other] authenticated users* (and especially "passwords") then yes, that's a flawed design. However, **there should be nothing about _presenting_ a login page that is insecure**.

Comment: @user2864740 "there should be nothing about *presenting* a login page that is insecure" - can you please explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Client side security is one thing the most important thing is the server side security, if a user is not authenticated he should have no way to even get any sensitiv data from the server at all

Comment: @Badgy Yes, I understand that server side security is very important. But my question IS about client side security. Including the login page in your SPA means the user is receiving all of the SPA's code from the server before they're even authenticated. Isn't that insecure? Why or why not?

Comment: It depends which Information is locked behind the Login

Comment: @torjinx tldr: The local login page does *not* perform authentication or leak any secrets, but uses a secure authentication/authorization providers (usually a web-service); cookies are common but not required. This is generally no different between an SPA and a page that performs 'a 1999 forms login'. Furthermore, **data access (again usually through a web-service) should limited per appropriate authorizations** - don't send private/sensitive cross-user information to the client, unless that client is authorized to have it. Authentication ensures the SPA is 'run by' a particular user.

Comment: ..and since authentication ties to authorization, ties to all future domain data access, authentication must be similarly secured by a "login web-service". Any secrets exposed by the SPA to the client that allow this authentication to be defeated are insecure.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An SPA would have all the page *structures* (html and javascript code for the design of pages), but obviously not data. Data would be downloaded in subsequent ajax requests, and that is the point. To download actual data, a user would have to be authenticated to the server, and all security would then be implemented server-side. An unauthorized user should not be able to access data from the server. But the idea is that how pages look is not a secret, anybody can have a look at pages of the SPA *without data*, and that's fine.

Well, and here comes the catch that people often overlook. Html is one thing, but there is all the javascript in an SPA that can access all the data. Basically the code of the SPA is an API documentation if you like, a list of possible queries that the backend can handle. Sure, it should all be secure server-side, but that's not always the case, people make mistakes. With such a "documentation" that an SPA is, it can be much easier for an attacker to evaluate server-side security and find authorization / access-control flaws in server-side code which may enable access to data that should not be accessible to the attacker.

So in short, having access to how pages look (without data) should be ok. However, giving away how exactly the API works can in certain scenarios help an attacker, and therefore adds some risk, which is inherent to SPAs.

It must be noted though that it should not matter. As security by obscurity should not be used (ie. it should not be a secret how things work, only things like credentials should be secrets), it should be fine to let anyone know all the javascript, or the full API documentation. However, the real world is not always so idealistic. Often attackers don't know how stuff works, and it can be of real help to be able to for example analyze an SPA, because people that write the backend code do make mistakes. In other cases the API is public and documented anyway, in which case having an SPA presents no further risk.

If you put the SPA behind authentication (only authenticated users can download the SPA code), that complicates CDN access a lot, though some content delivery networks do support some level of authentication I think.

Yet there is a real benefit of having a separate (plain old html) login page outside the SPA. If you have the login page *in* the SPA, you can only get an access token (session id, whatever) in javascript, which means it will be accessible to javascript, and you can only store it in localStorage, or a plain non-httpOnly cookie. This may easily result in the authentication token being stolen via cross-site scripting (XSS). A more secure option is to have a separate login page, which sets the authentication token as a httpOnly cookie, inaccessible to any javascript, and as such, safe from XSS. Note though that this brings the risk of CSRF, which you wil lhave to deal with then, as opposed to the token/session id being sent as something like a request header.

In many cases, having the login in the SPA and storing the authentication token in localStorage is acceptable, but this should be an informed decision, and you should be aware of the risk (XSS, vs CSRF in the other case).

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. So would you recommend separating the login page from the SPA, or do you think it's fine to include it as part of the SPA?

Comment: Well, that's a surprisingly complex question, and may be worth its own SO question. The short answer is that the benefit of having a plain old html login page is that (1) you can authorize downloading the SPA itself so that only logged in users can download the whole thing, and more importantly (2) the authentication cookie can then be set as httpOnly, which is a real protection against stealing the token via XSS. But in many applications, it is acceptable to include the login page in the SPA itself, and store the token in say localStorage - if you accept the associated risks.

Comment: Ah ok, I just realized this was the question. :) Sorry, I will edit the answer.

Comment: I don't agree with that. As far as I understand 75% of your argumentation is about having an ability to see all SPA codebase before auth. But in 99% of websites anybody can just create an account and get this codebase to analyze. So, unless this is a site for inherently closed group of people (corporate/government) it just does not make any difference. About httpOnly - what stops you from having httpOnly cookie in SPA? This is definitely not a reason for separation, same about CSRF. It is interesting that you mentioning login page protection while CSRF must be implemented in entire SPA anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that data loaded into an SPA must be secured behind an API through authn. But I think you can also secure layout so it is "less ok" having access to how pages look. With metamodel-driven development, you can serve layout configuration from a secured API. I am not talking about serving HTML (that's SSR), I am talking about serving JSON. That layout configuration is nothing but a JSON file on the server defining the content of your screen (fully or partially). Then your SPA code turns into a generic interpreter/render of that metamodel that parses the payload, renders components and binds data. If your API is L3, voilà, you get a fully working API-driven app.