# How can I have a separate login.html page for Angular application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot as a backend service and angular for front-end.
Ongoing through [Is it insecure to include your login page in your single page application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150090/is-it-insecure-to-include-your-login-page-in-your-single-page-application) , It says to have a separate login page.

I am using router in angular app,

```
  {path: 'dashboard',                     component:DashboardComponent              ,  canActivate : [DefaultGuard]     },
  {path: 'batch',                         component:BatchComponent                  ,  canActivate : [DefaultGuard]     },
```

Here, if user is not authenticated , i want to redirect to plain login.html.

In Spring boot, I tried to use formLogin(),

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
               http.
                 formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html",true)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html")
                    .permitAll()

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it insecure to include your login page in your single page application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150090/is-it-insecure-to-include-your-login-page-in-your-single-page-application)

Comment: @Soham, Nope it doesn't . I read that answer, But I want a example how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular guard . for more info check below links
https://github.com/gauribane/Angular-Service-layered-architecture-with-reuired-services-directive.git
https://codeburst.io/using-angular-route-guard-for-securing-routes-eabf5b86b4d1
https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: I am using Angular guards to check auth.  when not Authenticated, i wish to redirect to plain login.html page. But how can i redirect to seperate login Page to Users.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is that first only login page should be loaded without other code and after authentication other code should be loaded.

In your app component, only have login page component.

After login is success full then lazy load other module which have remaining code. Use canload guard on that module.

Its simple.