# Is it necessary to secure your webapp's code? In other words, not let the client get the actual js until the user has logged in?

Tags: javascript, spring, security, web-applications

I'm using Spring to serve the webapp, and also authenticate the user. So currently the user's browser can never get the javascript until the user logged in.

However, we're switching to a new login approach, which basically requires the webapp code to check if the user is authenticated... meaning the user's browser needs to get the webapp code before he's logged in. So the webapp code cannot be behind authentication.

Is this okay? I don't think there is anything confidential in our webapp code. No secrets or anything.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [security.se]. But unless the code contains the authentication method, or it contains confidential information, it's generally not considered a big concern.

Comment: That's totally okay, unless you don't want someone who hasn't logged in to see what your UI looks like and steal your design ideas or something jk. There's nothing much they can do, as long as you wrote your client correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it insecure to include your login page in your single page application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150090/is-it-insecure-to-include-your-login-page-in-your-single-page-application)