# SPA concept - login/register confusion

Tags: vue.js, web, single-page-application

I've recently started to use vue.js hence I've some doubts about my understanding of SPA.
Let's consider app like that:

- there is login/register home page,
- after being logged/registered dashboard with user data is displayed.

I understand that for home page request, view for dashboard is also send to client despite the fact that he isn't logged yet. And after login/register, request for data to feed dashboard is performed. This entails that not logged user can view structure of site available for logged one (of course without data only same structure). Does this understanding is valid?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53151223/6225326) which is highly relevant to your question.

Comment: This is really so, unless you have a separate FE app for sign-in.